# stretch animation on click when change product view

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

[Video with animation](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/259660/screenshots/14708656/media/abf342c99ed7fbf70bdb847830dbac7f.mp4)

How can I achieve a similar effect using css and js? I came up with the idea that each main box should have 3 images in it (image of the item preceding, current and next). I've even created such a layout, but I have absolutely no idea how to get such an animation when clicking on the buttons that change the product. [My layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ga6R.png)

EDIT: I added the html code of what I created. I have the individual product switches programmed in JS for now, so I won't post it here.

```css
.post_gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item {
  position: absolute;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:first-child {
  z-index: 0;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(2){
  left: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(3){
  left: 380px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:last-child{
  left: 540px;
  z-index: -3;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item .gallery_image a {
  display: block;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:first-child .gallery_image a,
.post_gallery .gallery_item:first-child .gallery_image a img{
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(2) .gallery_image a,
.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(2) .gallery_image a img{
  height: 450px;
  width: 360px;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(3) .gallery_image a,
.post_gallery .gallery_item:nth-child(3) .gallery_image a img{
  height: 400px;
  width: 320px;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item:last-child .gallery_image a,
.post_gallery .gallery_item:last-child .gallery_image a img{
  height: 350px;
  width: 280px;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item .gallery_image a img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item .gallery_image a img:first-child{
  background-color: red;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item .gallery_image a img:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.post_gallery .gallery_item .gallery_image a img:last-child{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="post_gallery">
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <a href="/product1" title="Product 1">
          <img src="../img/slide-4.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-1.png" />
          <img src="../img/slide-2.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <a href="/product2" title="Product 2">
          <img src="../img/Slide-1.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-2.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-3.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <a href="/product3" title="Product 3">
          <img src="../img/Slide-2.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-3.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-4.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <div class="gallery_image">
        <a href="/product4" title="Product 4">
          <img src="../img/Slide-3.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-4.png" />
          <img src="../img/Slide-1.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controllers">
    <button type="button" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button"></button>
    <button type="button"></button>
    <button type="button"></button>
    <button type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cześć :) It's easiest to play with `background-size`. It's about math.

Comment: The video is helpful. However, it is impossible to debug the issue without posting your code. Please post a [example].

Comment: @Kameron I added the html code of what I created. I have the individual product switches programmed in JS for now, so I won't post it here.

Comment: @bronisMateusz Please update the snippet I added to your question with any relevant CSS or JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer to this question, but you should accomplish what you are trying if you follow these steps:

1. Make it simpler by making sure all of your boxes have the same
   aspect ratio. That way you can easily resize images.
2. Specify ID for `<img>` tag.
3. Make sure to set `overflow: hidden;`. That way nothing with a offset in the box will be visible.
4. Set first image in box to `margin-left: 0%;`, second image to `margin-left: 100%` and third to `margin-left: 200%;` That will hide other two images because of hidden overflow.
5. Write Javascript code to change margin on user click, adjusting first item in box to `margin-left: -100%;`, second to `margin-left: 0%;` and so on.

You could check if `<img>` has `margin-left: 0%;` and if it has, you set, on click, every `<img>` with that value to `margin-left: -100%;`. Be sure to move every `<img>` with `margin-left:` -100% to `margin-left: 100%` to make it go in a circle. You can check for styles with `getComputedStyle()`.